# Oauth2 multiple AuthorizationServers in one app

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Is it possible to declare many OAuth2 authorization servers in one Spring Boot 1.4.1 app? I tried to do so, but every time only one authorization server is working at the moment.

I need it because I have two types of users that can login to my app and each of them must be separated. It's not only matter of role in a system but a purpose of the particular type of user.

So there is a way to do it that way? Or maybe I need to host two separate app, which will be my authorization servers and resource server separately?